# What is useState second parameter? And why am I having the "is not a function" error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mern, use-effect, use-state

I got this react app, I am using useState Hook to update the state inside useEffect:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

 export default function App() {
const {userData, setUserData} = useState({
    token : undefined,
    user: undefined
});

useEffect(() =>{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    const checkLoggedIn = async () => {
        let token = localStorage.getItem("auth-token");

        if(token === null){  
            localStorage.setItem("auth-token", "");
            token = "";
        }
        
        
        const tokenRes = await Axios.post(
            "http://localhost:5000/users/tokenIsValid",
            null,
            {headers: {"x-auth-token": token}}
        );

    
        if(tokenRes.data){
            const userRes = await Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/users/",{
                headers: {"x-auth-token": token},
            });

            setUserData({
                token,
                user: userRes
            });
        }
        console.log(tokenRes.data);
    };
    checkLoggedIn();
}, [setUserData]);
```

When I run that, I get this error:
[image]

I browsed this and found that sometimes is related to react, react-dom and react-router-dom version, and i checked them but they look updated:

package.json:

"dependencies": {
"axios": "^0.19.2",
"cra-template": "1.0.3",
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react-scripts": "3.4.1"
},

So I want to know what exactly does that second parameter, in this case "setUserData" return, and why am I getting this error.

thanks, regards.

Comment: It should be `const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});`. Notice the array destructing instead of object.

Comment: It solved! Wow thank you so much, I think it's because I have no clear idea of what "array destructing" is , I will investigate more about it, thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

Calling `useState` hook will return the state value and the setter function in an array with the first element being the state value and the second element being the setter function.

You should not be destructuring the value `userData` and `setUserData` from an object,

Try this instead

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
    token : undefined,
    user: undefined
});
```

**Note** There is no need for passing the value of `setUserData` as a dependency in the dependency array in `useEffect`

Comment: It solved! Wow thank you so much, I think it's because I have no clear idea of what "array destructing" is , I will investigate more about it, thanks again :)